# how do I redirect to my own custom logout page after the logout process has completed with .net core 5

Tags: redirect, .net-core, azure-active-directory, logout

Whenever I logout from my app Im taken to a 'default' logged out page (I believe this controller action is built in to .net core).  How do I perform a logout redirect to a custom page within my app after Ive been logged out ? I cant see a way to specifiy this, surely it must be possible ?  (it was in older versions of .net).
Im using azure ad and my app is hosted in azure.  This is the configuration

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
            options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
        });

        

        // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");
```

I also have these settings in appsettings.json

```
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
```

Ive also tried this

```
new RewriteOptions().Add(
            context => {
                if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/AzureAD/Account/SignedOut")
                { context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index"); }
            })
        );
```

and even tried adding my own AccountController with these 2 methods

```
[HttpGet]
    public override SignOutResult SignOut()
    {
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
        return SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignedOut()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }
```

Nothing works, Im always redirected to the 'default' logged out page.  Can anyone help ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this, I changd my Rewite code to this

```
app.UseRewriter(
        new RewriteOptions().Add(
            context => {
                if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut")
                { context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/SignedOut"); }
            })
        );
```

this was the part I had to modify
from

"/AzureAD/Account/SignedOut"

to

"/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut"

now it works